# Handling and returning data via POST request in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, backend

I want to implement web application, which accept user input, encode or decode it and then return it to the user's screen. I can accept user input and process it, but can't return it to screen.

Here is the code snippet:

```
exports.postEncDec = (req, res, next) => {
    let database64 = req.body.inputENC;
    let decodedBase64 = new Buffer.from(dataBase64, "base64").toString("ascii");
    console.log(decodedBase64);
};
```

Here I accept the data provided by the user and assign it to the dataBase64 variable.  Then I decode that data and assign it to the decodedBase64 variable.  Now I want to write this data to the input on the screen, but I can't.  How can I write this decoded data to the screen (I can just write it to the console)?

Comment: well you have to return it to the browser without further information I would assume, `res.end(decodedBase64)` but I could be wrong and I would recommend using a webserver library like express.js if you're gonna present html files etc

Comment: @Breezer yes, I want to send this data to the ejs file. How can I do this with the help of express.js framework ?

Comment: have you tried what I mentioned to you? either way you need to show more of your code what you have and what you havent done etc for us to help you further

Comment: I know express.js but I don't know what to use to solve this problem. I just need a way to send the post request data to the ejs files. I don't think any more code snippets are needed for this. For example, it is possible to do this easily with the render() method in the get request: exports.getEncDec = (req, res, next) => {
    res.render("base64.ejs", { data: 'something' });
};